# Exclude multiple tests with dotnet test --filter command

Tags: .net, testing

I am trying to exclude 2 name space from tests. I have try planty of option. but without result.

dotnet test --filter "not(FullyQualifiedName~TribesTests.EntitiesTest.BuildingTest) | (FullyQualifiedName~TribesTests.EndpointsTest)"

I have try
dotnet test --filter "not(FullyQualifiedName~TribesTests.EntitiesTest.BuildingTest) | (FullyQualifiedName~TribesTests.EndpointsTest)"

dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName!~TribesTests.EntitiesTest.BuildingTest | FullyQualifiedName!~TribesTests.EndpointsTest"

and many of another try

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `&` (and) operator instead of `|` (or):

```
dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName!~TribesTests.EntitiesTest.BuildingTest & FullyQualifiedName!~TribesTests.EndpointsTest"
```